# WPF - Referencing multiple resources

Tags: xaml, collections

Experts,

In XAML I would like to create a many-to-many relationship between entities.

Basically I would like for multiple "Manager" objects to be able to manage multiple "Items". The following XAML should describe what I'm looking for:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <cc:Manager x:Key="Manager1"/>
        <cc:Manager x:Key="Manager2"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <cc:Item>
        <cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager1" />
        </cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
    </cc:Item>
    <cc:Item>
        <cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager1" />
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager2" /> <!-- ERROR HERE -->
        </cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
    </cc:Item>
    <cc:Item>
        <cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager2" />
        </cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
    </cc:Item>
</Grid>
```

The attached property (Manager.ManagedBy) is of type `ManagedByCollection`...

```
ManagedByCollection : List<ManageBy>
```

With this I get the following error message:

```
The object 'Object' already has a child and cannot add 'StaticResourceExtension'. 'Object' can accept only one child. Line NN Position NN.
```

So, I wen't back to MSDN and realized there's a ContentPropertyAttribute to tell the XAML compiler what property is the default one when nothing else is specified. The LinearGradientBrush, for example, uses that attribute to enable us to write just ...

```
<LinearGradientBrush ... >
   <GradientStop ... />
   <GradientStop ... />
   <GradientStop ... />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

... instead of ...

```
<LinearGradientBrush ... >
   <GradientStopCollection>
       <GradientStop ... />
       <GradientStop ... />
       <GradientStop ... />
   </GradientStopCollection>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

So, I was thinking I just needed to specify the indexer of `ManagedByCollection` as the class' ContentProperty:

```
[ContentProperty("Item")
ManagerCollection : List<Manager>
```

Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue. Currently the following works...

```
<cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
    <ManagerCollection>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager1" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager2" />
    <cc:ManagerCollection>
</cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
```

... but, again, I would prefer the more readble syntax:

```
<cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager1" />
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Manager2" />
</cc.Manager.ManagedBy>
```

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the collection explicitly in the constructor of `Item`:

```
public Item()
{
    Manager.SetManagedBy(this, new ManagedByCollection());
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case I would like to figure out how reference other XAML entities from collection items without having to explicitly create a collection, like you can with `LinearGradientBrush` and `GradientStop` items.

Comment: @JonasRembratt, they work the same way; LinearGradientBrush initializes its GradientStops collection so that items can be directly added to it in XAML

Comment: Not sure I understand. I do realize there's a difference to my scenario in that I'm working with an _attached_ property whereas GradientStops is a normal property. I tried setting the default value for the attached property to the correct collection but I still get this run time error:

`'Spike.ManyToManyXAML.Manager' is not a valid value for property 'ManagedBy'.`

Comment: You can't set a default value for the attached property, because if you did all objects would share the same collection

Comment: Silly me! But it really doesn't matter (I would get other kinds of problems if it did work with a default collection instance) so the question remain: Is there a way to go about building a collection based attached property that wouldn't require explicit declaration of the collection instance?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-initialize-an-attached-dependencyproperty-of-type-collection.aspx

Comment: That solution actually almost worked! All I needed to do was catch the setter and and adjust the logics depending on whether the assigned value is a collection or an item. Thanks!